# Hibernate vs SQL:Best way to Update column of all rows in a table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, sql-update

I have a database table alert and am using Hibernate.I am using mySQL.

I want to update all columns of the database.
The table name is alert where as the mapping class of the table is Alert.

**Using SQLQUERY:**

```
session.beginTransaction();
session.createSQLQuery("update alert set retryCount=3"); 
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

is not working.

**Using HQL** using dynaming update attribute

```
Query query=session.createQuery("from Alert");
for(int i=0;i<query.list().size();i++){
   Alert alert=(Alert)query.list().get(i);
   alert.setretryCount(3);
   session.update(alert);
 }
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

is working

Though the second one is working I think it will take much more time than a normal sql query.Is it so?Whats the best way to update a set of columns of all rows while using hibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi ! Have you tried this ?

```
session.beginTransaction();
String queryString = "update Alert a set a.retryCount=3"
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
session.executeUpdate(query);
session.close();
```

This is on the hibernate official documentation. This is an HQL request using entities as objects and not as SQL tables. I think it's better to do it this way since you don't need to care about your database model.

Could you give us the displayed stacktrace for the non-working method ?

Comment: It will be query.executeUpdate()?

Comment: Well, this way is the way of updating elements using hql queries. If you want to retrieve data (i.e select in SQL) you can use the list() or the uniqueResult() method. If you want to delete, insert or update data, you might use the executeUpdate() method.